# Need help to simplify the derivative

Tags: derivatives

Can someone tell me what would be the output of this equation?
$$\frac{d}{dx}[\cos^4(x)\cdot\cos (x^4)] = -4x^3\cdot\cos^4(x)\cdot\sin (x^4)+4\cos(x^4)\cdot\cos^3(x)\cdot\sin(x)$$

But am not getting the same answer, would like to know what would be the answer? Could you please derive and show me?

Thanks,
-Kamal.

Comment: the second term should have a negative sign too; not a plus sign as you have it.

Comment: I removed the tag "differential equations" because this is not a differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use product rule to find:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[   \cos^4(x)\cdot \cos(x^4)\right]=\cos(x^4)\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos^4(x)+\cos^4(x)\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos(x^4)
$$
than chain rule gives
$$
= -4\cos^3(x)\cdot\sin(x)\cdot\cos(x^4)-4x^3\sin(x^4)\cdot\cos^4(x)
$$

Comment: This is exactly the answer I got, thanks bad textbook.